# Map colors to labels in ggplot based on background color

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

How does one change the color of the text in ggplot? For example, I have a stacked bar plot. I want to make the labels black when the background is light blue or green.

Here is a meaningless dummy sample:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df <- mpg %>% 
  mutate(cyl = as.character(cyl)) %>% 
  group_by(model, cyl) %>% 
  summarize(hwy = mean(hwy), .groups = "keep") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(model) %>% 
  mutate(hwy = round(hwy / sum(hwy), 2)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  head(11) %>% 
  mutate(color = case_when(cyl == "4" ~ "white", 
                           cyl == "6" ~ "black", 
                           cyl == "8" ~ "black"))

df %>% 
  ggplot(data = ., aes(x = model, y = hwy, fill = cyl, label = hwy)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill") + 
  geom_text(color = "white", position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("dark blue", "light blue", "green"), 
                    name = "cyl",
                    breaks = c("4", "6", "8"),
                    labels = c("4", "6", "8"))
```

[image: plot]

I tried using `scale_color_manual`, as in this example ([More than 1 color in geom_text()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209899/more-than-1-color-in-geom-text)) but it didn't work. The solution in this example didn't even work for me on the sample in the question itself. Maybe because it's 8 years old, idk.

Either a solution that chooses colors dynamically in the `ggplot` call based on the fill color or one that maps the "color" variable to text colors would work.

Comment: Related: [Contrast between label and background: determine if color is light or dark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49437263/contrast-between-label-and-background-determine-if-color-is-light-or-dark);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Borrowing a code snippet from `scales::show_col` to set the label colors according to the luminance of the fill colors to either "black" or "white" one option to achieve your desired result may look like so:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(carver)

fill_colors <- c("dark blue", "light blue", "green")
# Borrowed from scales::show_col
hcl <- farver::decode_colour(fill_colors, "rgb", "hcl")
label_col <- ifelse(hcl[, "l"] > 50, "black", "white")

df %>% 
  ggplot(data = ., aes(x = model, y = hwy, fill = cyl, label = hwy)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill") + 
  geom_text(aes(color = cyl), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), show.legend = FALSE) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = fill_colors, 
                    name = "cyl",
                    breaks = c("4", "6", "8"),
                    labels = c("4", "6", "8")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = label_col)
```

[image]

Comment: Both answers are nice. I chose this because of the nugget of wisdom in `decode_colour`. That's potentially really powerful, especially with mapping like in @Rui Barradas' answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since you already have the colors you want, white and black, computed in the `mutate` statement, map `color = cyl` (the same as the `fill` aesthetics) and add a `scale_color_manual` with the required values.

```
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = model, y = hwy, fill = cyl)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill") + 
  geom_text(aes(color = cyl, label = hwy),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
            show.legend = FALSE) + 
  scale_fill_manual(name = "cyl",
                    values = c("dark blue", "light blue", "green"), 
                    breaks = c("4", "6", "8"),
                    labels = c("4", "6", "8")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("white", "black", "black"),
                     breaks = c("4", "6", "8"))
```

[image]

Comment: Why not `geom_text(color = df$color, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))`. Style issue? Not to use `$` inside `ggplot`?

Comment: @TarJae You are right, I was being lazy. Corrected now.